# What is the benefit of using a private member in a get instead of just having the class auto set the property itself?

Tags: c#, properties

I see this kind of thing all over the place in our code.

```
public int SomeValue
{
    get { return _someValue; }
}
private int _someValue;
```

Then, the class sets _someValue and external accessors must use SomeValue to see the value.

What is the benefit of doing this instead of just setting the property to get only and then having the class set SomeValue internally?

```
public int SomeValue { get; }
```

Adding the extra private variable seems to just bloat the code.

Comment: The code could potentially be from before auto properties were introduced.

Comment: Indeed, until C# 6, there were no read-only autoprops.

Comment: As @itsme86 has said, it's probably outdated code.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne, *OutDated* would be a wrong word here. But indeed it's a legacy code

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes sense.  I've been refactoring a lot of them to be auto properties and there has only been one instance where it didn't work.  That was where the internal variable was passed by ref.  That's easy enough to work around, though.

Comment: How would you set this property if it's readonly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int SomeValue
{
    get { return _someValue; }
}
private int _someValue;
```

is not the equivalent of

```
public int SomeValue { get; }
```

If you do the auto property it is equivalent to

```
public int SomeValue
{
    get { return _someValue; }
}
private readonly int _someValue;
```

You can not change the value of `_someValue` internally with the auto property but you could with the original code.

That being said, based on your comments, the code was most likely written before C# 6 when auto read only properties where introduced and the original author was too lazy or did not know that he could mark `_someValue` as `readonly` and did not intend for `_someValue` to be changed anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.  Turns out I just got lucky on my first hundred or so changes.  They were were only getting set in the constructor, so it worked for them.  As soon as I started finding properties that were set later on, changing it to get only no longer worked, as you described.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update your code to newer syntax the equivalent is:

```
public SomeValue { get; private set; }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you use this auto property, what can you do if you want to change that value during program running?

> [A property without a set accessor is considered read-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)